# Use CSS to specify columns

Tags: html, css

How to use CSS to place items into columns without changing the order of the html tags?

```
<ul>
  <li class="column-2">1</li>
  <li class="column-1">2</li>
  <li class="column-1">3</li>
  <li class="column-3">4</li>
  <li class="column-3">5</li>
</ul>
```

Should look like this:

[image]

As items are added they should fall into their specified column (Tetris style).

Comment: "as list items are added" - why not create 3 `<div>` columns of 33% width and prepend the items to the correct div?

Comment: If you can support HTML5, you could use the `flex` layout, with the order attribute. See [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp) for more information and try it

Comment: the picture you have shown is what you want rite ?

Comment: u may want to explain a bit more so i can help you :)

Comment: With float:left, fixed width, and setting margin-left to something positions it in the correct column. But the margin-left leaves empty boxes of whitespace.

Comment: @AlexandreFILLATRE Can you provide an example?

Comment: @dippas solution is what I meant. The W3C site has code you can try (and change) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS grid with `grid-auto-flow: column;` achieves the effect I was looking for.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.column-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.column-2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.column-3 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column-2">1</div>
  <div class="column-1">2</div>
  <div class="column-1">3</div>
  <div class="column-3">4</div>
  <div class="column-3">5</div>
  <div class="column-1">6</div>
</div>
```